# Пойдёт ли Xamarin под виртуальной машиной или нужен Хакинтош?

Tags: ios, vmware, virtualbox

Здравствуйте.

Попросили написать небольшую программку (спец калькулятор) для IPhone и выложить её в Аппстор. Под андроид на Xamarin studio я её уже почти дописал. Теперь необходимо портировать её на IPhone. Как мне это проще всего сделать? Я так понимаю, у меня есть 2 варианта - либо виртуалка + xamarin, либо Хакинтош + xamarin? (Вариант с покупкой мак бука для написания одной программки я считаю нецелесообразным!)

Вариант 1:
Возможно ли вообще писать и компилить приложения для IPhone на Xamarin studio из-под виртуальной машины Mac OS? Просто я слышал, что вроде как IOS SDK возможно использовать только под IOS, виртуальная машина не катит. Кто нибудь пробовал? Расскажите, что к чему.

Вариант 2:
Есть ли возможность поставить на мой комп (на отдельный жесткий диск) хакинтош? Конфигурация компа: 
core i7 2600
мать: Asus P8Z68-V le
4Gb DDR3
видео: GTX 460 v2
Версия BIOS:   American Megatrends Inc. 0401, 21.06.2011 
Если да, то какую сборку посоветуете?

Comment: андро**и**д

Answer (score 1):

Ставь тупо vmplayer, образ mac os туда накатываешь, пробуй деплоить. А вообще phonegap еще как один из (не самых лучших) вариантов. Xamarin вроде как у тебя и из-под windows должен нормально работать. Отпиши обязательно по результатам, скоро предстоит нечто похожее реализовывать.

Answer (score 0):

У меня с виртуалкой не сложилось. После установки WMWAre обвалились эмуляторы андроид и виндофона. К тому же образ на WMWare криво встал, всё равно ничего не получилось. Пришлось всё переустанавливать.

В итоге на втором компе поднял хакинтош и по сети, из MS Visual Studio 2015 под Xamarin тестил прогу на ios-эмуляторе XCode.
[Процесс подъёма хакинтоша описан здесь](https://codedocs.ru/hakintosh/ustanovka-hakintosh-mac-os-x-10-11-5-el-capitan.html)